# cas jasig using oracle data source on windows

Tags: cas

is there any way that can help cas settings to use the data source oracle on windows

in my company will apply singgle singgle sign on and logout, I've been trying for 5 days, and until now have not been successful.

I've tried several ways

## I use

1. Tomcat 7.0
2. Java 1.7
3. cas server 3.5.2

Tomcat 7.0
Java 1.7
cas server 3.5.2

1. I downloaded cas server 3.5.2
2. extract cas-server-3.5.2
3. copy cas-server-webapp-3.5.2.war into tomcat webapps
4. cas has been successfully deployed, and can be accessed

and then I do not understand anymore, how do I get the authentication process can use oracle database

sorry my english is not good

thank you

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things you need to do:

First of all, if you haven't downloaded and included the Oracle JDBC Driver library (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html) then you have to do that.

Secondly, you need to configure the JDBC plugin: https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/JDBC

These instructions (and the preferred method of customizing & building CAS) uses the Maven Web Overlay method. This has the advantage that you deploy lots of un-necessary libraries that you aren't using.